# keyboard automatically appearance, does it use broadcastreceiver or InputMethodService for this?

Tags: android, keyboard

I am trying to make a demo project, As per this project whenever user click on edittext in any activity, the activity of my application gets started

So I am confuse regarding that whenever we click on edittext in any activity in any app, whether its fb, whatsapp, LINE etc the keyboard automatically appears 
does it use broadcastreceiver or InputMethodService for this
and if its use InputMethodService and if i am not wrong this InputMethodService is a type of Service and service has  a demerit that the system sometimes kills background services automatically to free memory. But the keyboard appears everytime we click on edittext.
So can anyone tell please how the keyboard everytime appears whenever we click on edittext.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**InputMethodService**  is the service which detects when to show the android Keyboard,
This service is an android system service.

You could try making Service and do a research on it. You can use the code below and implement your intent in showSoftInput () method.

```
     import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
     import android.os.IBinder;
     import android.os.ResultReceiver;
     import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
     import android.view.inputmethod.InputBinding;
     import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
     import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethod;
     import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodSession;
     import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodSubtype;

 public class MyService extends InputMethodService implements InputMethod{

@Override
public void attachToken(IBinder token) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void bindInput(InputBinding binding) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void changeInputMethodSubtype(InputMethodSubtype subtype) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void createSession(SessionCallback callback) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void hideSoftInput(int flags, ResultReceiver resultReceiver) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void restartInput(InputConnection inputConnection,
        EditorInfo attribute) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void revokeSession(InputMethodSession session) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void setSessionEnabled(InputMethodSession session, boolean enabled) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void showSoftInput(int flags, ResultReceiver resultReceiver) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  Run your APP here
    //Intent to your acticity
}

@Override
public void startInput(InputConnection inputConnection, EditorInfo info) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void unbindInput() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



   }
```

Comment: so I want to start my application whenever keyboard appears so do my class extends InputMethodService?

Comment: no i want my application to be launch whenever the edittext of any application clicked, whether its of fb, whatsapp, Line. whenever the edittext of any application clicked, my app gets launch

Comment: @DevilAbhi  i dont think that is possible

Comment: whenever the keyboard appears will this service be called?,,, and do i declare <service android:name="MyService"/>,,,and how to start this service on the creation of activity?

Comment: @nawaab saab are you able to find the solution of (launch whenever the edittext of any application clicked, whether its of fb, whatsapp, Line. whenever the edittext of any application clicked, my app gets launch ) I need to do something similar.Thanks